# Warnings On Updating Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: updates

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:8 https://debian.neo4j.com stable InRelease                                
Hit:9 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:11 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]   
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyzardking/ubuntu-make/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slyon/iwd+nm/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:18 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/swi-prolog/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 228 kB in 2s (98.1 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/source/Sources', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/binary-amd64/Packages', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/i18n/Translation-en', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/i18n/Translation-en_GB', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/dep11/Components-amd64.yml', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/dep11/icons-48x48.tar', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/dep11/icons-64x64.tar', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'mysql-5.7/cnf/Commands-amd64', as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-5.7' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/binary-amd64/Packages', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/i18n/Translation-en', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/i18n/Translation-en_GB', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/dep11/Components-amd64.yml', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/dep11/icons-48x48.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/dep11/icons-64x64.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'focal-updates/cnf/Commands-amd64', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'focal-updates' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/binary-amd64/Packages', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/i18n/Translation-en_GB', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/i18n/Translation-en', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/dep11/Components-amd64.yml', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/dep11/icons-48x48.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/dep11/icons-64x64.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'deb-src/cnf/Commands-amd64', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'deb-src' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//binary-amd64/Packages', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//i18n/Translation-en_GB', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//i18n/Translation-en', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dep11/Components-amd64.yml', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dep11/icons-48x48.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dep11/icons-64x64.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//cnf/Commands-amd64', as repository 'http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**/etc/apt/sources.list file**

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates focal-updates restricted deb-src main http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates focal-updates restricted deb-src main universe http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

Comment: There's a lot to untangle here. With all of those added sources and PPAs there's probably a conflict somewhere. There also might be additional `.list` files under `/etc/apt` or subfolders. The more sources you add, the greater the likelihood there will be a conflict that will cause problems. For this reason it's not a good idea to install a bunch of software this way. I suggest that you do some clean up and remove anything you don't really need. For example, MySQL is in official repos, you don't need to add a PPA for that. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/35629

Comment: The output suggests that several of the issues are simple typos that you can easily fix. After you fix those, show us the /etc/apt/source.list.d/ file for the remainders that are not caused by typos.

Comment: But they can't be typos as they were added by the installation process itself. isn't it at least possible that an error could lie in the installation process for update repo links ?

Comment: @Nmath. Taking out mysql references takes the warning count to 27 - down from 37.

Comment: *"they can't be typos as they were added by the installation process itself"* - Only 4-5 of those sources are Ubuntu sources that were the only ones that existed after Ubuntu was installed.  All of the rest of these sources would have been added by you at some point, probably at various times when you installed this software. But these sources could not have been added by simply installing software with apt or your GUI software center. Maybe you entered commands, or maybe you edited the sources.list file directly

Comment: I added repo links via command line usually, occasionally via Software & Updates. Never by directly editing /etc/apt/sources.list. All per instructions for the software package installation provided. And I had no issues until I found Ubuntu was not updating itself to 20.04.4. After that was corrected via AskUbuntu advice, I tried to install neo4j yesterday. Then the warnings and errors erupted.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you used a command or if you edited sources in a text editor - the result is the same. You need to correct the typos. There's usually multiple ways to install the same software, with adding sources being one of the messiest. PPAs are often provided for latest and beta versions, and that is not always a good decision because the consequence of adding sources is that some sources may call different/conflicting versions of dependencies that can wreck your package management. Use the version in repos when you can. See my link above & also https://askubuntu.com/q/151283